# New command for local setlength

Tags: align

I'm looking for local space settings after math text, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
ax_{1}^{2}+bx_{1}+c=y_{1} \\
ax_{2}^{2}+bx_{2}+c=y_{2} \\
2ax_{1}+b=0
\end{align*}
\footnotesize\textit{Soustava tří rovnic o třech neznámých s jedním řešením pro dvě různá} $x_{1}$ \textit{a} $x_{2}$\textit{.}
```

Space setting after that align. I've found just parameters for the whole document:

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
```

Nevertheless, I tried to create a command:

```
\newcommand{\mezery}[2]{{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{#1}}{\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{#2}}}
\mezery{0pt}{0pt}
```

but it doesn't work. What's wrong? Could I eventually put `\mezery{0pt}{0pt}` between `align` or other environment? Won't the command be executed for the whole document, as well?

Comment: they are local settings. You would need to put it before the align and end after it, using `{}` or any other scoping although it is very unusual to change this mid document are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: When I put it before and after align, it ain't working. It's working putted just after 'begin document'. When I put it between align, the effect is not complete. Does there exist any other math environment with that parameter?

Comment: You can't set them _inside_ the align otherwise their effect is just one cell of the alignment and gone by the time these lengths are used

Answer (score 11):

`\setlength` is a local setting. See the following which uses three different settings on your example

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\raggedright

aaaaaaa
\begin{align*}
ax_{1}^{2}+bx_{1}+c=y_{1} \\
ax_{2}^{2}+bx_{2}+c=y_{2} \\
2ax_{1}+b=0
\end{align*}
aaaaaaaa

{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
aaaaaaa
\begin{align*}
ax_{1}^{2}+bx_{1}+c=y_{1} \\
ax_{2}^{2}+bx_{2}+c=y_{2} \\
2ax_{1}+b=0
\end{align*}
aaaaaaaa}


{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{30pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{30pt}
aaaaaaa
\begin{align*}
ax_{1}^{2}+bx_{1}+c=y_{1} \\
ax_{2}^{2}+bx_{2}+c=y_{2} \\
2ax_{1}+b=0
\end{align*}
aaaaaaaa}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, already working. Satisfactory math environment, after all... What about that command? Could it execute sth like \setlenght? Or is it just incorrectly entered?

Comment: Your defined command does nothing as it is just does `{\setlength\abovedispayskip{0pt}}` That is it starts a group sets the length then immediately ends the group which resets the length to what it was, it would be like `\newcommand\mybf{{\bfseries}}` which would not make anything bold for the same reason